# Dynamic path positioning between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to find the best way of dynamically positioning the blue path. The important part is its position relative to `b` and `c`. I currently am using `\path [line,blue] let \p1=(a.south), \p2=(c) in (h.south) |- +(2,-0.5)  |- (\x2, \y1) -- (c.north);` for the blue path, but it really doesn't give me much dynamic control.

I've thought about trying add a couple of let points and taking the middle of their x-values, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. It would look something like: `\path [line,blue] let \p1=(a.south), \p2=(c), \p3=(b.east), \p4=(c.west) in (h.south) -| +( AAA , -0.5)  |- (\x2, \y1) -- (c.north);` where `AAA` would be something like `($(\x3 !0.25! \x4)$)` or `(\x3 + \x4)*0.75` but that really seems like a kludgy way of doing it.

So, what's the best way to draw this path so that it will scale dynamically??

Also open to any suggestions on improving the red path.
[image: path]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%\input{../tikz-setup.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, 
                        draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em 
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 5pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]
\tikzstyle{line}    = [ draw, -triangle 45 ]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = flush center, font = \small]
    % Place nodes
    \matrix [column sep = 3em, row sep = 1.2em] (mtrx)
    {

    \node [state] (a) {a};\\

    \node [action] (b) {b}; &
    \node [test] (c) {c}; \\

    \node [action] (d) {d}; &
    &
    \node [action] (e) {e}; \\

    \node [action] (f) {f}; &
    &
    \node [action] (g) {g}; \\

    \node [action] (h) {h}; \\
    };

    % Draw edges         
    \path [line, red] (c.west) -- ($(b.east)!0.75!(c.west)$) |- ($(e.south)!0.5!(g.north)$);
   %\path [line, red] let \p1=(e), \p2=(f), \p3=(c.west), \p4=(b.east) in (c.west) -- ($(\x3, \y3)!0.25!(\x4, \y3)$) |- ($(\x1, \y1)!0.5!(\x1, \y2)$); %alt

    \path [line,blue] let \p1=(a.south), \p2=(c) in (h.south) |- +(2,-0.5)  |- (\x2, \y1) -- (c.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: try this

  \path (b.east) -- (b.east-|c.west)coordinate[pos=0.25](xx) ;
  \path[line,blue] (h.south) |- ($(h.south east) +(0,-0.5)$) -| (xx) -- (a.south-|xx) -|(c.north);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%\input{../tikz-setup.tex}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, calc, positioning}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{state}   = [ rounded rectangle, 
                        draw, 
                        text centered, 
                        minimum height=3em 
                      ]
\tikzstyle{test}    = [ diamond, 
                        draw, 
                        shape aspect=2, 
                        inner sep = 0pt,
                        text width = 7em,
                        text centered
                      ]
\tikzstyle{action}  = [ rectangle, draw,
                        text width=8em,
                        inner sep = 5pt, 
                        minimum height=5em
                      ]
\tikzstyle{line}    = [ draw, -triangle 45 ]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[align = flush center, font = \small]
    % Place nodes
    \matrix [column sep =5em, row sep = 2em] (mtrx)
    {

    \node [state] (a) {a};\\

    \node [action] (b) {b}; &
    \node [test] (c) {c}; \\

    \node [action] (d) {d}; &
    &
    \node [action] (e) {e}; \\

    \node [action] (f) {f}; &
    &
    \node [action] (g) {g}; \\

    \node [action] (h) {h}; \\
    };

    % Draw edges         
    \path [line, red] (c.west) -- ($(b.east)!0.75!(c.west)$) |- ($(e.south)!0.5!(g.north)$);


  \path (b.east) -- (b.east-|c.west)coordinate[pos=0.25](xx) ;
  \path[line,blue] (h.south) |- ($(h.south east) +(0,-0.5)$) -| (xx) -- (a.south-|xx) -|(c.north);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

la ligne

```
\path (b.east) -- (b.east-|c.west)coordinate[pos=0.25](xx) ;
```

permet de créer un point intermédiaire entre les deux noeuds (b) et (c). Il ne reste plus qu'à relier les points

---

The line

```
\path (b.east) -- (b.east-|c.west)coordinate[pos=0.25](xx) ;
```

creates an intermediate point between the two nodes `(b)` and `(c)`. The remaining step is to connect the dots.

Comment: It is good practice to add a bit of an explanation when posting an answer. Please be a little more explicit and make your answer more than a comment.

Comment: @percusse :Thank you for the translation, I generally translate, but I was pressed for time

merci pour la traduction, en général je traduis, mais la j'étais pris par le temps

Comment: @rpapa Je vous en prie.